# convert TZ date format to "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I get date_time from mssql db.
Currently date come like that

```
 2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z
```

When I use this method;

```
    const date =date;
    var d = new Date(date).toUTCString()
```

My date is looking like

```
Sat, 30 Jan 2021 15:08:25 GMT
```

But, ı want to see date "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've checked in my Chrome tools JS you can mix up this methods:

```
const date = new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').toLocaleDateString('us')
const hours = new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').toLocaleTimeString('us')
console.log(`${date} ${hours}`)
```

and concat that results

**Edited**. I've found that

```
new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').toLocaleDateString('fr')
```

is way similar to what date format you need

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I write this, an hour comes 1 day and 3 hours ahead.

Comment: `\`${new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').toLocaleDateString('fr')} 
${new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').getUTCHours()}:${new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').getUTCMinutes()}:${new Date('2021-01-30T15:08:25.393Z').getUTCSeconds()} \``   
Try to do something like that then.

Comment: It was that way, you helped a lot, thank you

Comment: The output of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, especially when no options are provided. That a particular language code/tag provides a certain format on one implementation does not mean the same format will be produced by other implementations.